Is there a better way to declare a generic container of containers?
I am defining a set of classes that deal with pages of items and the enveloping objects that contain these pages. These "envelopes" are, in fact, generic response bodies from services. Declaring generic classes for these concepts was a simple task but, after defining concrete types for the paginated responses, I end up with declarations that seem redundant.
Simplified example code:
class PagedResponse<I, T extends Page<I>> {
    public T data;
    public List<I> getItems() {
        return this.data.getItems();
    }
}

abstract class Page<I> {
    public abstract List<I> getItems();
}

class ConcreteItem {
    /* data & code */
}

class ConcreteItemPage extends Page<ConcreteItem> {
    public List<ConcreteItem> getItems() {
        /* ... */
    }
}


void loadConcreteItemPage() {
    PagedResponse<ConcreteItem, ConcreteItemPage> response = /* call service, get response body */;
    List<ConcreteItem> itemsInPage = response.getItems();
    /* iterate through items */
}

By "redundant", I mean the declaration of the response variable needing to be parameterized with ConcreteItem, even though the ItemPage type parameter is already parameterized with the same ConcreteItem type. It seems the declaration should be simply like this...
PagedResponse<ConcreteItemPage> response = /* call service, get response body */;
List<ConcreteItem> itemsInPage = response.getItems();

...but I don't know how to do it within the Java type system, or if it is even possible. Thank you!

Could you not just do class PagedResponse<I> and public Page<I> data;?

@ipodtouch0218 maybe, if I could have a way of having more than one type of Page (the actual use case demands it).

Page<I> would allow any subclass of Page that specifies type I. So for your example, Page<I> would become Page<ConcreteItem>, which is what ConcreteItemPage is. If you had another class like class ConcreteItemPage2 extends Page<ConcreteItem>, it would also be allowed.

This would technically change the implementation, since PagedResponse could have it's data field changed to any Page<I> instead of just the one type specified at creation: response.data = new ConcreteItemPage() and response.data = new ConcreteItemPage2() would both be valid. If that's fine, then the Page<I> data would work.

@ipodtouch0218 That would be acceptable. In this case, what would the declaration of PagedResponse look like? (The point is, trying to remove the I type parameter from it.)

You'd have to either keep I (so getItems can return a definite type) or return List<object>. Did you mean that you wanted to remove T extends PageData<I>? If so, I just posted an answer with what the new code would look like.

You can change out class PagedResponse<I, T extends PageData<I>> with class PagedResponse<I> and use Page<I> data for your data field:
public class PagedResponse<I> {
    public Page<I> data;
    public List<I> getItems() {
        return this.data.getItems();
    }
}


This would technically change the implementation though, as the data field would now be reassignable to any Page<I> subclass after creation:
public class ConcreteItemPage extends Page<ConcreteItem> {
    ...
}

public class AlternativeConcreteItemPage extends Page<ConcreteItem> {
    ...
}

// Before
PagedResponse<ConcreteItem, ConcreteItemPage> response = ...
response.data = new ConcreteItemPage(...); // Vaild
response.data = new AlternativeConcreteItemPage(...); // Invalid
List<ConcreteItem> itemsInPage = response.getItems();

// After
PagedResponse<ConcreteItem> response = ...
response.data = new ConcreteItemPage(...); // Vaild
response.data = new AlternativeConcreteItemPage(...); // Also valid
List<ConcreteItem> itemsInPage = response.getItems();

